# How can we make LoRaWAN work in Real World

Tags: lora

Today, there are many competitive IoT providers and technologies initiated by many organisations across the world. Sigfox and LoRa Alliance I believe are in the top of the competition line but, please feel to correct me if I am wrong. However, these companies are limited by theories expressed in wireless communication and all unknown physical laws. I think its fair for me to divide wireless communication into two segments; Wide-band and Narrow-band for the sake of my question.

I recently stumbled upon this document by TI which explains why Narrow Band is the De-Facto Standard for IoT.

http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/TI-Long-range-RF-communication.pdf

The above document make it sound like, rather prove, that future IoT communication solutions that use large number of nodes should use minimum bandwidths possible. They highlight the fact that "co-existance" can only be achieved through Narrow-band. This makes me wonder how LoraWAN achieves the same as it goes without argument that any IoT technology that doesn't support co-existance is of no use in future. I know that LoRAWAN protocol limits the number of transmissions done through a unit node by setting a limit of the daily quota. I ( I hope you too) see that on its own is not sufficient to support co-existence of thousands of nodes.

As I learnt, LoRaWAN/LoRa PHY does not use Narrowband technology but uses a modulation technique called Spread Spectrum which utilizes a higher bandwidth. I believe this limits the total number of nodes that can transmit at the same time within a given spectrum(e.g. the ISM band). At the same time, radios that utilize narrow-band technologies can support  higher number of simultaneous transmissions using the same spectrum.

I an keen to know how LoRA would support co-existence in future applications in situations where few thousands of nodes involved.

I would also like to know the possible outcomes when two LoRa nodes transmit at the same frequency at the same time from the same place with exact same power. Would data get corrupted?

I also know that the people who invented LoRA are way better at wireless technologies than I am. Hence, I would like to know what possible reasons may have caused them to stick to Spread Spectrum technology rather than narrow band. Or did they do a mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shorten your question to make it accessible and don't promote semi-contentious ideas like "radios that utilize narrow-band technologies can support higher number of simultaneous transmissions using the same spectrum" AND "unknown physical laws". These two points are not correct and they put me off answering AND also your question is too broad. Cut the chaff and get to a single answerable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At an equivalent link margin (~transmission range) narrow band transmissions are more spectrally efficient than spread spectrum modulations.

OTOH narrow band transmissions requires an accurate and stable clock source to transmit an receive properly. For long range transmissions, the channel has to be very narrow and the needed clock source is expensive and requires lots of power.

As networks, LoRaWAN and Sigfox **work in Real World** technically, despite using different trade-offs. They both can be used to deploy networks with a wide coverage at an unbeatable price/km² covered, they both have a capability to scale (with different trade offs). The economic equation seems all right, and politics (and some luck) will be a deciding factor for the future.

Take everything published by TI on that matter with a huge grain of salt. When the first LoRa transceivers appeared on the market they released a video (I can't find it anymore) showing them performing extremely poorly. I do not believe TI engineers are incompetent, and the technology perform as advertised in neutral hands, so the only option left is malice.

Answer (score 2):

In general, spread spectrum systems are less prone to interference since the transmitting/receiving frequencies are always changing. This technique puts less average power out on a given frequency and with the proper spreading algorithm, collisions are therefore more easily avoided. All of this comes at the expense of more complexity in the RF decks (transmitter and receiver) and therefore often higher  costs.

Narrow channel methods include collision avoidance and detection algorithms in their protocols. But since all devices share a channel or a group of channels, the bandwidth per device goes down as more devices are added. Generally, narrow band systems have lower costs due to their simpler RF decks.

There are many other factors to be considered that are well beyond the scope of this forum but you will find sufficient data on the Internet if you wish to delve further into this topic.